# How to authenticate with NTLM with parameters (via HTTP)?

Tags: c++, winapi, ntlm, sspi

I'm using [InitializeSecurityContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375512(v=vs.85).aspx) function to produce Type 1 and Type 3 messages for NTLM authentication in HTTP. Everything works fine when I'm receiving default header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
```

But, when I receive header like:

```
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM realm="SIP Communications Service", targetname="server.domain.com", version=4
```

It is not going to accept Type 1 message and I'm receiving again all WWW-Authenticate headers.
This is the function that I use to produce first response:

```
result = SSPI()->InitializeSecurityContextW(
    credHandle, // phCredential
    0, // phContext
    0, // *pszTargetName
    ISC_REQ_USE_DCE_STYLE | ISC_REQ_DELEGATE | ISC_REQ_MUTUAL_AUTH
        | ISC_REQ_REPLAY_DETECT | ISC_REQ_SEQUENCE_DETECT
        | ISC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY | ISC_REQ_CONNECTION, // fContextReq
    0, // Reserved1
    0, // TargetDataRep
    0, // pInput
    0, // Reserved2
    context, // phNewContext
    bufferDesc, // pOutput
    &outFlags, // pfContextAttr
    &timestamp // ptsExpiry
);
```

I tried already to set pszTargetName as L"server.domain.com" but it doesn't work too.

Any ideas how I could pass realm, targetname and version parameters (if necessary)?
I am communicating with Lync 2013 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to authenticate by using [MS-SIPAE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd944123(v=office.12).aspx) documentation and NTLM authentication example. Entire process is well described in above link.